# Submit id and value of textbox with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hey guys im trying to process the id and the value of a textfield when a use enters a number. I am currently using this script for the submit:

```
<script>
function warenkorb(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","towarenkorb.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And my textbox looks like this:

```
<input id="'.$resultarray3['ID'].'_k" onchange="warenkorb(this.value)" type="text">
```

So what do i have to change that my script is doing this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","towarenkorb.php?q="+str+"&ID=" + rtr,true);
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
function warenkorb(str, id) {
```

and

```
<input id="'.$resultarray3['ID'].'_k" onchange="warenkorb(this.value,'.
   $resultarray3['ID'].')" type="text">
```

Please take in mind that I make an assumption that your ID is an integer. If it isn't, you may want to wrap the `$resultarray3['ID']` in quotes.

Comment: Thanks thats so easy that i didn't even thought about it. :D

Comment: Go take a nap or grab a coffee - this one was easy indeed :)